# Calcular modulo 11 factor 2

Tags: python

estoy intentando calcular el modulo 11 factor 2 de un número de 48 digitos en python tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
def GenerarClaveAcceso(clave_acceso_48):
    """Funcion encargada de crear la clave
        de Acceso con 49 digitos basado en
        la metodologia mod 11 factor 2
    """
    print clave_acceso_48
    contador = 1
    data = []
    for clave in clave_acceso_48:
        element = {}
        if contador == 1:
            element['digito_1'] = int(clave) * 3

        if contador == 2:
            element['digito_2'] = int(clave) * 2

        if contador == 3:
            element['digito_3'] = int(clave) * 7

        if contador == 4:
            element['digito_4'] = int(clave) * 6

        if contador == 5:
            element['digito_5'] = int(clave) * 5

        if contador == 6:
            element['digito_6'] = int(clave) * 4

        if contador == 7:
            element['digito_7'] = int(clave) * 3

        if contador == 8:
            element['digito_8'] = int(clave) * 2

        if contador == 9:
            element['digito_9'] = int(clave) * 7

        if contador == 10:
            element['digito_10'] = int(clave) * 6

        if contador == 11:
            element['digito_11'] = int(clave) * 5

        if contador == 12:
            element['digito_12'] = int(clave) * 4

        if contador == 13:
            element['digito_13'] = int(clave) * 3

        if contador == 14:
            element['digito_14'] = int(clave) * 2

        if contador == 15:
            element['digito_15'] = int(clave) * 7

        if contador == 16:
            element['digito_16'] = int(clave) * 6

        if contador == 17:
            element['digito_17'] = int(clave) * 5

        if contador == 18:
            element['digito_18'] = int(clave) * 4

        if contador == 19:
            element['digito_19'] = int(clave) * 3

        if contador == 20:
            element['digito_20'] = int(clave) * 2

        if contador == 21:
            element['digito_21'] = int(clave) * 7

        if contador == 22:
            element['digito_22'] = int(clave) * 6

        if contador == 23:
            element['digito_23'] = int(clave) * 5

        if contador == 24:
            element['digito_24'] = int(clave) * 4

        if contador == 25:
            element['digito_25'] = int(clave) * 3

        if contador == 26:
            element['digito_26'] = int(clave) * 2

        if contador == 27:
            element['digito_27'] = int(clave) * 7

        if contador == 28:
            element['digito_28'] = int(clave) * 6

        if contador == 29:
            element['digito_29'] = int(clave) * 5

        if contador == 30:
            element['digito_30'] = int(clave) * 4

        if contador == 31:
            element['digito_31'] = int(clave) * 3

        if contador == 32:
            element['digito_32'] = int(clave) * 2

        if contador == 33:
            element['digito_33'] = int(clave) * 7

        if contador == 34:
            element['digito_34'] = int(clave) * 6

        if contador == 35:
            element['digito_35'] = int(clave) * 5

        if contador == 36:
            element['digito_36'] = int(clave) * 4

        if contador == 37:
            element['digito_37'] = int(clave) * 3

        if contador == 38:
            element['digito_38'] = int(clave) * 2

        if contador == 39:
            element['digito_39'] = int(clave) * 7

        if contador == 40:
            element['digito_40'] = int(clave) * 6

        if contador == 41:
            element['digito_41'] = int(clave) * 5

        if contador == 42:
            element['digito_42'] = int(clave) * 4

        if contador == 43:
            element['digito_43'] = int(clave) * 3

        if contador == 42:
            element['digito_42'] = int(clave) * 2

        if contador == 43:
            element['digito_43'] = int(clave) * 7

        if contador == 44:
            element['digito_44'] = int(clave) * 6

        if contador == 45:
            element['digito_45'] = int(clave) * 5

        if contador == 46:
            element['digito_46'] = int(clave) * 4

        if contador == 47:
            element['digito_47'] = int(clave) * 3

        if contador == 48:
            element['digito_48'] = int(clave) * 2

        contador += 1
        data.append(element)

    contador = 0
    sumatoria = 0
    for valor in data:
        contador += 1
        indice = 'digito_' + str(contador)
        sumatoria += int(valor[indice])

    mod = sumatoria % 11
    resultado_resta_mod = 11 - mod

    if int(resultado_resta_mod) == 11:
        digito_verificador = 0

    elif int(resultado_resta_mod) == 10:
        digito_verificador = 0
    else:
        digito_verificador = resultado_resta_mod
```

El codigo como ven es demasiado extenso, me genera un digito pero mi duda es si esta bien desarrollado y si existen quiza alguna forma de hacer menos extenso el calculo del mismo.

Para realizar esta funcion use la documentacion siguiente:

[Digito Verificador Modulo 11](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_control)

De antemano muchas gracias.. !!

Comment: Diego, revertí tu edición anterior y eliminé mi respuesta ya que la misma solo apuntaba a la optimización de tu código, para una respuesta más completa verifica la de @Abulafia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo con la definición del algoritmo en Wikipedia, los factores a usar son 2,3,4,5,6,7 *comenzando por el dígito menos significativo*, y repitiéndose luego a medida que seguimos hacia los dígitos más significativos.

Tu implementación en cambio usa `3,2,7,6,5,4` comenzando por el más significativo, lo cual es válido sólo si la secuencia de entrada tiene una cantidad de dígitos que sea múltiplo de 6 más 2. No es el caso para tu secuencia de entrada con 48 dígitos, que es múltiplo de 6, luego lo estás calculando mal.

Para evitar este tipo de errores y para que sea válido para cualquier longitud de la entrada, es mejor operar comenzando por el dígito menos significativo, para lo que podemos usar `reversed()` sobre la secuencia de entrada.

Además, haciendo uso de `itertools.cycle()` podemos obtener la secuencia repetitiva de `2,3,4,5,6,7,2,3,4,5...` tan larga como necesitemos, lo que simplifica mucho la sintaxis necesaria a la vez que lo hace más genérico.

Quedaría así:

```
import itertools

def GenerarClaveAcceso(clave_acceso_48):
  factores = itertools.cycle((2,3,4,5,6,7))
  suma = 0
  for digito, factor in zip(reversed(clave_acceso_48), factores):
    suma += int(digito)*factor
  control = 11 - suma%11
  if control == 10:
     return 1
  else:
     return control
```

La función `zip(secuencia1, secuencia2)` va devolviendo parejas de elementos, uno de cada secuencia, hasta que una de ellas se agote. En nuestro caso la `secuencia1` es la de los dígitos de entrada, pero "al revés", para comenzar por el menos significativo. La `secuencia2` es la que genera `itertools.cycle()`, que es infinita (o tan larga como se necesite). En este caso se acabará antes `secuencia1`. De este modo funciona para cualquier tamaño de la entrada.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
>>> GenerarClaveAcceso('241120180118901536380012003004000255333002553331')
6
```

Comment: genial gracias funciono ..!!

Answer (score 0):

Implementé un pequeño script con Faker para generar Rut chilenos falsos para poblar una base de datos de prueba. Básicamente lo que hice fue generar un número aleatorio el cual lo convertí a string y luego a lista para poder iterar sobre él.

La iteración la realicé de atrás hacia adelante, eliminando el último elemento de la lista hasta quedarme sin lista.

Esta fue la implementación del método que hice, se puede hacer más elegante pero sirvió para lo que necesitaba:

```
def rut(self):
        num = random.randint(10000000,19999999)
        tmp = list(str(num))
        total = 0
        sumando = 2
        while tmp:
            if sumando == 8:
                sumando = 2
            total += (sumando * int(tmp[-1]))
            sumando += 1
            del tmp[-1]

        dig = 11-(total%11)

        if dig == 10:
            dig = "k"
        elif id == 11:
            dig = "0"
        else:
            dig = str(dig)

        return str(num)+"-"+dig
```

Espero que te sirva. Salu2